# Why can't I test undefined variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this:

```
    var currentpage = page ? page : null;
```

However, if page is not yet defined, the script throws an error. Even if I test page for being undefined, as soon as the script looks up page it errors.

Why and what's the way around this issue?

**Update : Made the code-example clearer;**

Comment: can you post the lines of code that are above this line page ? 'page=' + page : ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to read from an undeclared variable simply throws a `ReferenceError` and terminates the script.

```
> x123
ReferenceError: x123 is not defined
```

The better question is, why you don't know whether your variable exists. Under normal circumstances, this usually implies you're doing something **bad**. Why is it that you need to check for that situation? Surely, there is a better way that we could suggest.

Comment: correct, but if you write the test like this : if `(undefined === test)` then it works

Comment: @nimrod My Chrome still gives me a ReferenceError. [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/k2eG7/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof` operator for that:

```
var a = (typeof page != 'undefined') ? 'page=' + page: '';
alert(a);
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but shouldn't testing for undefined values work?

Comment: @nimrod If you access the variable directly and the variable does not exists the interpreter will throw an error, that is the correct behaviour and it's the same way in all dynamic languages, like PHP for example, in PHP we have to protect access with isset() function in the same manner we here use typeof

Answer (score 1):

You must have defined the variable somewhere using `var page` or as a function argument `function (page)`. If you did this anywhere within the same scope, the variable is declared and exist, even if it has no value. If you're trying to work with some variable that is not even declared in the same scope, that's simply wrong because it cannot work under any circumstance and Javascript is entirely correct to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around would be like this, Even if your `var a` is undefined the else will be executed, that is your script won't stop execution

```
 if(window.a){
      alert('hello'); 
    } else {
      alert('this else will fire');
    }
```